# Windows Server 2008 redirected folder files disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, folder-redirection

I had setup a Windows 2008 server to redirect My Documents using Group Policy. A user using Win7 had a couple of documents saved to My Documents and was good for a couple of days. One day I run Windows Update as an admin and it installs Win 7 SP1. After the install the computer reboots and the user logs in and all of the My Documents are gone. Can't find anywhere in the Users directory on the local computer and neither on the server.

One thing I did notice is the timestamp of the My Documents folder on the server for the user was set to the time the user logged in after SP1 was installed?

Did anyone else run into this issue and any ideas how the files could be recovered other than from backup?

Comment: Service packs don't delete files, locally or from servers.

Comment: are you using client side cacheing?

Comment: Did you actually check the settings of the Documents folder and verify they are redirecting to where you think they are going?  Start, Right Click on Documents.  Should show the folder path where it is redirecting.  Do other machines redirect correctly?

Comment: Run RSOP and check applied settings

Comment: Simply restore with shadow copy ? check if the user got a new profile locally on the computer, as if your gpo is set to migrate the data it could act bad if the profile got somehow corrupted with the sp, as it would migrate an empty my docs

Answer (score 1):

I would double check your GPO settings to make sure you're looking for the files in the correct locaitons. I've seen them be put in all sorts of different locations \server\users, \server\profiles, etc. I've seen some places have both of those setup. Best way to make sure you have the right one is to check the GPO setting. If they still aren't there, well, that's what the backup is for.

Comment: thanks for your reply. No the location didn't change in the GPO and I can see all other My Document folders for other users. It's just for this one user that everything disappeared.

Comment: Did the files disapear? or the whole folder? A service pack will not delete things from a computer, more or less a server. Whatever happened to them, I would fall back to your Backups.

Comment: Nixphoe,The whole folder disappears and it happened again but this time no updates were installed.

Comment: Setup auditing on that folder. That should get to the bottom of it.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277403.aspx